# Authorization of microservices in monolith application

Tags: django, jwt, microservices

I have a django application that puts a task in a queue. Another service is used to read that queue and process some files. At the end I need to save the processed files in the database managed by the django application.

I do not want to give the **microservice** access directly to the database, since I want the responsibility only to be to process the files.

So I wanted to post the changes to django using HTTP request. The problem is that I do not have any authorization at the time, even though I know that HTTP from this type of machine is to be accepted.

For the django application I use JWT as an authorization token. How is the best way to approach this type of problem? Maybe just send a token together to the queue? But how to make such token? It's not certain when the process will be executed..

Answer (score 0):

When you really think about it, there is no need for your internal services to authenticate themselves if they are in the same network.

In that case - You can put Django behind an API gateway (don't write your own, find an open source highly rated project). Then you can control via this gateway which end point is allowed by which traffic source. Then you can easily control end points that are specifically for internal services and which end points need authentication by an external entity.

If they aren't in the same network (which means they are separated by the great gulf of the cloudy net) then the usual way two machines communicate is with an API key. In that case, you can configure your services with symmetric keys, or private/public pair, it doesn't really matter. Machines can be trusted with secret keys. Why would you need to send the token in the queue? If the service is allowed to post results to Django, its allowed to do so for all requests, so it needs to be configured with an API key that tells your API that it is allowed to post processed files.